# One-off redefinition of the section numbering

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning, page-numbering, line-numbering

I use a the article class and have set the following:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}}
```

This makes my `\section{Test 1}` to `I. Test`. My documnent also has a header on each page specifying the current section.

```
I. Test 1
_________________________________

Text Text Text
```

The ToC then also shows:

```
Contents

I Test 1                             pagenumber #
```

Now I would like to create an appendix such that the header in the running document is:

```
Appendix A: Figures
___________________________________

My appendix page
```

and the ToC to show

```
Contents

I Test 1                             pagenumber #
Appendix A: Figures                  pagenumber #
```

Is it somehow possible to redefine the command such that I can choose whether numbering yes or no, but still use the `\section` command such that the "setioning" in the running document is shown?

Because doing:

```
\section*{Appendix A: Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A: Figures}
```

does delete the numbering, also puts the `Appendix A: Figures` into the ToC, but this also leads to that in my running document does not show the header line "Appendix A: Figures" which I do need, otherwise the headerline just shows the previous line, which in my case is "References" called via

```
\bibliography{References}
```

Comment: Thanks @John Kormylo: any ideas what I need to adapt to get there?

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo: I use the article class. Would it help if I provide my preamble?

Comment: .Oops.  `\@seccntformat` is in source2e as part of `\@startsection`  The default is `\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}`  So all the change did is replace `\quad` with `.\hspace{0.5em}`.  And yes, it would help to provide a MWE (minimal working example which demonstrates the problem (and as little else as possible).

Comment: You might move the period to \thesection.